# Moving Textview Using Buttons Android

Tags: java, android, xml, button, textview

What i'm trying to do is when you click any of the arrow buttons shown in the image, the TextView user_text will move a small amount in the respective direction.  For some reason using the Java code below when I click on the buttons, the text moves all the way to the absolute edge of the screen.  I wasn't sure why this was happening so I decided to try and use  `user_text.getX() and user_text.getY()` to get their X and Y coordinates but that didn't do anything.  After a little research, I found that I should've been using `user_text.getLeft() and user_text.getTop() and/or user_text.getWidth()`.  After trying those, the android monitor/debug section of the studio said that those numbers were 0.  I'm not sure why this happened but if someone could tell me what I should be doing instead or how to get it so that every time you click the button it moves, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

P.S. I wrote on the image so you would know what is being ID-ed as `user_text`

[image: reference image]

My relevant XML Code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="120dp" />
  .    <--- that is supposed to represent that there's other non-relevant code in between
  .
  .

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/move_Group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/move_left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/arrow"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:onClick="moveLeft"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/move_up"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/move_left"
        android:background="@mipmap/arrow"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:onClick="moveUp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/move_down"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/move_up"
        android:background="@mipmap/arrow"
        android:rotation="180"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:onClick="moveDown"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/move_right"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/move_down"
        android:background="@mipmap/arrow"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:onClick="moveRight"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/move"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MOVE"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/move_right"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My relevant Java Code:

```
TextView user_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_text);
.
.
.
public void moveLeft(View view)
{
    user_text.setX(userX + 10);
}

public void moveUp(View view)
{
    user_text.setY(userY + 10);
}

public void moveDown(View view)
{
    user_text.setY(userY - 10);
}

public void moveRight(View view)
{
    user_text.setX(userX - 10);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get current X and Y of `user_text` in click function.

```
public void moveLeft(View view)
{
      user_text.setX(user_text.getX() - 10);
}
```

when move up: Y = Y - delta.

```
public void moveUp(View view)
{
       user_text.setY(user_text.getY() - 10);
}
```

when move down: Y = Y + delta

```
public void moveDown(View view)
{
    user_text.setY(user_text.getY() + 10);
}
```

This is example in MainActivity.java. I see it works

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView user_text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        user_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_text);

    }

    public void moveLeft(View view)
    {
        user_text.setX(user_text.getX() - 10);
    }

    public void moveUp(View view)
    {
        user_text.setY(user_text.getY() - 10);

    }

    public void moveDown(View view)
    {
        user_text.setY(user_text.getY() + 10);

    }

    public void moveRight(View view)
    {
        user_text.setX(user_text.getX() + 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please leave some explanation